How should we discuss unpalatable legal opinions?
Context: The USA is currently partway through a well-understood, well-documented reactionary backslide, eroding democracy and rule of law. In anticipation of an electoral victory later this year, The Heritage Foundation has published Project 2025, a blueprint for more restructuring. Quote:

Paul Dans, the project's director, explained that Project 2025 is "systematically preparing to march into office and bring a new army, aligned, trained, and essentially weaponized conservatives ready to do battle against the deep state." … Critics of Project 2025 have described it as an authoritarian, Christian nationalist movement that seeks to reform the United States into an autocracy. Several experts in law have indicated that it would undermine the rule of law and the separation of powers.

I have noticed a pattern in discussions about 303 Creative and Masterpiece. For standing, I'll only link to my question on the topic, but there have been other similar questions. The pattern is one of aggressive nuance:

Surely 303 Creative doesn't actually say what it says…
Well actually, Masterpiece is about details of jurisdiction and regulation…
Any sort of actual discrimination would clearly be precluded by other law…

As well as some nastier arguments that shouldn't be ratified:

Well, unlike the plaintiffs in those cases, your hypothetical person doesn't have a sincerely held religious belief…
Well actually, there's a big difference between expressing a belief and performing labor…

What does 303 Creative actually say? Here's Sotomayor's introduction from her dissent (PDF, p33):

Today, the Court, for the first time in its history, grants a business open to the public a constitutional right to refuse to serve members of a protected class. Specifically, the Court holds that the First Amendment exempts a website-design company from a state law that prohibits the company from denying wedding websites to same-sex couples if the company chooses to sell those websites to the public. The Court also holds that the company has a right to post a notice that says, "'no [wedding websites] will be sold if they will be used for gay marriages.'"

And, further, they make it clear that this is ruling is an abomination:

A business open to the public seeks to deny gay and lesbian customers the full and equal enjoyment of its services based on the owner’s religious belief that same-sex marriages are "false." The business argues, and a majority of the Court agrees, that because the business offers services that are customized and expressive, the Free Speech Clause of the First Amendment shields the business from a generally applicable law that prohibits discrimination in the sale of publicly available goods and services. That is wrong. Profoundly wrong.

How should we discuss this? Right now, it does not seem to me like any of the questions about this topic are being answered in the manner I'd expect of a knowledge base. I've suggested adding tags specifically for Masterpiece discussion, and I suppose for 303 Creative discussion as well, but I'm not sure how to improve the quality of answers.

We fundamentally aren't capable of recognizing the real-life consequences of the legal system. We are only capable of discussing the law as a theoretical structure. The main limitation on our answers is the inability to be authoritative; because we do not require contributors to be qualified legal professionals, we cannot give legal advice.
The optimism or indifference of contributors towards the practical outcomes of actions taken by the legal system may indeed be "unpalatable," but it is a natural consequence of allowing candid good-faith introspection into the structure of the law. It is not our place to dictate the law, merely to study it.

Learn something from this.

We don't discuss. We provide answers to questions about the law. I don't know what "aggressive nuance" is, but I would expect that answers be as nuanced as the law happens to be.
Bounties are an underused way to encourage better or different answers. And if you have a better answer to an existing question, you can provide it yourself.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
